# Logitech C920 on Ubuntu, I can't save any settings

Tags: 22.04, video, webcam, camera

I don't know whats faulty, camera model or Linux video drivers in general. It's impossible to tune camera and save those settings. They get reset on boot, USB connect/disconnect, select/deselect in Meet settings, when change browser, when change camera program, even when I stop video temporarily in the call.

On all these events I am supposed to re-run shell script to set exposure settings. Even then one settings that work in Firefox are too dark in Chrome. Also properties are bound so when I restore value for exposure then white balance might get out of tune. In GUI apps sliders get stuck, manual modes not always work and sliders still move automatically, also exposure is impossible to tune, i.e. 1280 is too dark, 1281 is too light there is no continuous range.

For live calls and interviews it's completely useless.

I have tried `v4l-utils, cameractrls, guvcview` to tune it and preserve settings, it's impossible.